# Laravel migrate unknown database

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, composer-php

I am having some errors with laravels php artisan migrate command, when I try to migrate, it keeps throwing errors saying, unknown database 'database name'
I have checked my database configure file and even copied to a different project and it works perfectly there, I have tried composer dump-autoload command but that didn't solve the problem either. Please I will really appreciate if someone helps, since this is a new project and can't afford to lose even a minute to my deadline, thanks in advance!

The command I run from the terminal while I have CD'ed into the project folder is.

```
php artisan migrate
```

This is the error I get.

```
[PDOException]
SQLSTATE[42000] [1049] Unknown database '[gicfamily4]'
```

Comment: are you certain you're looking at the config file for the correct environment?

Comment: Yes I am sure @watcher

Comment: can you update your question with the exact error that laravel is throwing? also, ensure that your database has already been created in mysql prior to running the migration

Comment: Hi @watcher I have updated the question with the error and the command I run, thanks in ad.

Comment: I would search my entire project folder for the text _database name_, it has to be set somewhere.

Comment: Hi @hebron, I have updated the question with the exact database name I used in my database configure file, and that is the actual thing it shows in the error.

Comment: Oh sorry, I misunderstood. Can you confirm that the database _gicfamily4_ actually exist and that the settings and database type in config/database.php is correct?

Comment: I have done that but still giving me the same error.

Comment: In the `connection` array, do you have multiple `mysql` entries?

Comment: No, i have only one!

Answer (score 1):

```
[PDOException]
SQLSTATE[42000] [1049] Unknown database '[gicfamily4]'
```

This is a MySQL error and is indicative of either a misconfiguration in your environment's database.php config file (misspelling in the database name) *or* the database `gicfamily4` simply doesn't exist on the database server you are connecting to.

Verify your connection information again.  If possible, try to attempt to connect to the mysql server from the command line using the exact same information contained in your database.php file (via copy and paste):

```
$ mysql -u <username from database.php file> -p -h <database host from database.phpfile>
Enter Password: <paste password from database.php file>

mysql> use gicfamily4;
```

I suspect you will get the exact same error as above.

Comment: you are right, when i typed the name it gave me an error, but when i copied the name and pasted in the terminal it worked, but what surprises me is that what i typed and what i copied are the same, although when i copied and pasted to my config file, just like i did with the terminal, it still bounced back an error when i ran php artisan migrate.