# php artisan migrate - tables not created in phpMyAdmin

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, artisan-migrate

I am following this tutorial here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jbt5bEgv_QM and got stuck in the php artisan migrate part because of this issue. I'm not sure if it's compatibility issue or something. I am fairly new to laravel.

Here's the `database.php` file and `.env` file.

[image: database.php]

[image: env]

UPDATE: i managed to perform the migration using the solutions provided by the user PHP. However, i couldn't find the table in my phpMyAdmin. do i need to change mySQL root password for that? i have actually set the password but in `.env` and `database.php` files i left it blank because the migration works that way. if i set the actual password in both files, I'd get `access denied` error.

Here's the migration files...
[image: createuser]
[image: jobsfail]
[image: passwordreset]

Comment: Please read this question and see if it helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51448958/mysql-server-8-0-keyring-migration-error-at-login

Comment: hmm I'm not sure if it's related to my issue since i remember my password very well. p/s: i've updated the error above.. i put the wrong one earlier

Comment: It says "unknown database". Is it possible that you mistyped your database name?

Comment: i think i did not mistype my database name. I've checked all files including the one in phpMyAdmin multiple times to make sure.. and that database exists when i checked using `mysql > show database;` command

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQLSTATE\[HY000\] \[1045\] Access denied for user 'username'@'localhost' using CakePhp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31154124/sqlstatehy000-1045-access-denied-for-user-usernamelocalhost-using-cakep)

Comment: Refer: https://stackoverflow.com/q/31154124/10086603

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of what can be posted as text (in a code block).

Comment: @WhatIf the migration is successful now but the table is not created in the database.. i have updated the questions above.

Comment: @Falady Okay, fine. I confirm it as "Migration ran but table not created". Did you check in "migrations" table?

Comment: @WhatIf yes the necessary tables exists but not in my database which is on phpmyadmin.

Comment: @Falady Check whether the migration name is in "migrations" table.

Comment: post your migration file

Comment: @Erich i have updated the question.. assuming that it is the correct table you're referring to

Comment: @Falady not a picture of your files.  what table is not being created?  post the contents of the file itself (i.e. the code inside 2019_08_19_create_THE_TABLE_THAT_IS_NOT_BEING_CREATED_table.php)

Comment: if the table you're expecting to see in phpmyadmin doesn't have a migration file named similarly, it won't be created.

Comment: @Erich have a look at the updated above. and no i couldnt find the migrations table on phpmyadmin.

Comment: @Falady `php artisan migrate:install` isn't a command you normally have to run.  if it does not exist already, that table will be created the first time you migrate.

Comment: @Erich after many attempts and solutions, i decided to discard this project and create a new one. but then, the first time i try to run `php artisan migrate`, it throws an error saying `unknown database`.....the database exists in the server though.

Comment: @Falady https://stackoverflow.com/q/25921825/4468423

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**1)First you have to Create your related Database.**

**2)Then:php artisan cache:clear**

**3)Now run php artisan migrate:install**

Comment: I have created the database on phpMyAdmin and executed exactly the same steps above..

Comment: Can you get answer?

Comment: no.. i'm still getting the same error every time.. i have tried pretty much all solutions available online

Comment: except that i changed the port number in mySQL server which is in the program file in C. and i redo everything again from the start using the same file on git.. and i get the error `unknown database`.. i have created the database though.

Comment: the migration is successful using your solutions.. but the table somehow is not created in the database. i have updated my question above

Comment: Sorry 'php artisan migrate'

Comment: Yes I did that, but the table is still not created in the database...

Comment: First you run  php artisan:refresh  and then run php artisan migrate

Comment: php artisan migrate:refresh

Comment: php artisan migrate

Answer (score 1):

Had this issue with a Laravel 10 project and running these commands sorted it for me (run them one by one in the order I've typed them):

```
php artisan config:cache
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:clear
php artisan route:clear
composer dump-autoload
php artisan migrate:fresh --seed
```

Comment: This answer would benefit from an explanation of why these commands work, to discourage people blindly copying and pasting from the Internet without knowing or understanding what they are doing

Comment: The commands clear laravel caches for route, config etc and generate optimized files. The last command creates tables in the database a fresh and seeds them a fresh too

Answer (score 0):

`php artisan migrate:rollback` `then run php artisan migrate.`

*If you make changes to your migration files,* simply run `php artisan migrate:refresh`

Comment: I did that already..does it have anything to do with root password? In the `.env` and `database.php` I left the password blank, when there is actually a real password. But if I set the password in both files, it will throw `access denied`

Comment: please don't throw darts at the problem and post them as separate answers.